# Conditionally calling __str__ in models.py in accordance to the "related_name" Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Okay so here is my `models.py` first:

```
class UserFollowing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name="followers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} follows {self.following_user}"
```

So in this case, when I try like this:

```
>>> user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=1)   # just a user
>>> user.following.all()                  # A follows B
>>> user.followers.all()                  # B follows A
```

However, I want to do it like this:

```
>>> user.following.all()                  # B (Since A is following B)
>>> user.followers.all()                  # B (Since B is a follower of A)
```

But how can I differ the `__str__` outputs according to the `related_name`? I couldn't find any information on this so is there a way?

Comment: You *don't*. A method is attached to an object, not on the "origin" of that object.

Comment: Okay. So what I wanted to achieve by doing this was check if a specific user is following or is a follower of another user. How would I achieve this??

Comment: but it does not matter. You can simply access the users that are related and *then* render it in the template. You can add a `ManyToManyField` on `CustomUser`, with your `UserFollowing` model as `through=....` model, to make querying easier. In other words, you do not *need* to access the `UserFollowing` model here for rendering in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__str__` method takes into account the object (`self`), not the origin of that object. So how you constructed that object, through a `.following` or `.followers` is irrelevant. While it might be possible by inspecting the call stack, etc. it is simply not a good idea to do this.

You however do *not* need this. You are only interested in the `CustomUser`s that are "*followers*" or "*followees*" of a `CustomUser`, not the `UserFollowing` model that presents this. Therefore it might be better to span a `ManyToManyField` between `CustomUser` and `CustomUser` with `Follow` as `through=…` model:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    # …
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        symmetrical=False,
        through='Follow',
        related_name='followees',
        through_fields=('followee', 'follower')
    )

class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        related_name='followings',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    followee = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        related_name='followedby',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} follows {self.following_user}'
```

Then you thus can access the `CustomUser`s who are following user with:

```
b.followers.all()  # [c]
b.followees.all()  # [a]
```

here `b` is thus following `a`, and `c` is following `b`. These are thus `CustomUser` objects, not `Follow` objects.

Comment: Wow thanks for the real good comment. I might take some time in understanding this, but I'll try my best!

Comment: So according to your code, the `.followers.all()` does work, but the `.followees.all()` doesn't work for me. It says `AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'followees'`... But I'm guessing that If I wanted to do this I would have to make another field named `followees` in the `CustomUser`  class??

Comment: @SihwanLee: did you use `related_name='followees'` in the `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: yes I literally copied your stuff and checked in the shell to see if it worked @Willem Van Onsem